# I can't sleep in Minecraft: Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Every time I click on a bed, it briefly comes up with 'leave bed' and I don't click it. However, after less than a second, I'm out of bed again and therefore can't sleep.

Is this a glitch? Is anyone else experiencing the same problem or knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

There may be mobs outside your house which are moving inside the "You may not sleep now, there are mobs nearby" radius, so it cancels the sleep.

Answer (score 1):

There must be carpet blocking the way.

I have experienced this before and it was carpet.

Comment: Yeah. `carpet.`